# Same parent revision twice for a mercurial changeset

Tags: mercurial

Is there a canonical explanation why the same parent revision is listed twice for a given mercurial changeset resulting from a merge.

Unfortunately, we do not have a chance to tell, what exactly caused this situation in the observed case. It might be that the situation was caused by trying to perform an empty merge operation.

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out a possible way to cause this kind of situation...

The situation can easily be reproduced with TortoiseHG by selecting your local version and "Merge with local" checking the option "Discard all changes from merge target (other) revision".

This does not result in calling `hg merge` (as one could assume), but `hg debugsetparents`. So we shot ourselves in the foot by forcing Mercurial to set both parents to the same revision.